# Improper data type return when creating API request in Rocket Universe

Tags: universe, unidata, u2

We encounter this error message “improper data type” at production but in UAT environment is working fine. It also hang at submitRequest.Please advise.

Below is our coding

```
0001: TEXT="" ; RHANDLE = ""
0002: DL="|"   
0003: RESULT=createRequest("http://10.136.68.46:50003/WebApi/vehicle/VVV5555/icno/1111111111","GET",RHANDLE)   
0004: CRT "RESULT":RESULT
0005: CRT "RHANDLE":RHANDLE
0008: RESULT=submitRequest(RHANDLE,"5000","AmtIn=":TEXT,RHEAD,RDATA,RSTAT)
0009: CRT "RESULT":RESULT
0010: INPUT DUMMY
```

Result

RESULT0

RHANDLE Program "TWL.VIX11": Line 5, Improper data type.

Comment: This is nothing to do with the Tcl language, as far as I can see, so it should not be tagged with `tcl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is due to the setting in the /etc/hosts/
Add the following in the last line of the file

10.136.68.46 webapisvr